Context not created during migration in layered architecture
I'm trying to learn Onion Architecture with .net 8. I prepare dbcontext registration in persistance layer and add it to program.cs in presentation but I'm having an error. What is the problem, how can i solve it ?
This the error:
PM> add-migration mig1
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The exception 'C:\Users\oktay\Desktop\Dev\Presentation\theNewsServer.API' was thrown while attempting to find 'DbContext' types. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
Solution tree
this is my dbcontext
public theNewsServerDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

}

public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }



public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
   
    var datas = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>();

    foreach (var data in datas)
    {
        _ = data.State switch
        {
            EntityState.Added => data.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            EntityState.Modified => data.Entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            _ => DateTime.UtcNow, 
        };
    }

    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

my service registration for IoC container
public static void AddPersistenceServices(this IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddDbContext<theNewsServerDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.ConnectionString));

    
    services.AddScoped<INewsReadRepository, NewsReadRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<INewsWriteRepository, NewsWriteRepository>();
}

and finally program.cs
using theNewsService.Persistence;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddPersistenceServices();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200")
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()));
I try to migration with Entity Framework and got a error.

And what is the error?

PM> add-migration mig1
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The exception 'C:\Users\oktay\Desktop\Dev\Presentation\theNewsServer.API' was thrown while attempting to find 'DbContext' types. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

This question is asked here all the time. Have you opened the link? There are three ways to solve the problem.
